# multiple inheritance can't Support in C#. why?

Tags: .net-3.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp)
>   [Multiple inheritance is not supported in dotnet. But multiple interface supports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437563/multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-dotnet-but-multiple-interface-supports)

c# can support single inheritance. it uses only interface. but why it can't support multiple inheritance.....

Comment: possible duple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c

Answer (score 6):

going through google, found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/why-doesnt-c-support-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: +1 I was about to post this myself.