# Multiple inheritance is not supported in .NET. But are multiple interfaces supported?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Multiple Inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp)

Multiple inheritance is not supported in .NET. But multiple interface are supported. Why does this kind of behaviour exists?
Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 4):

You can simulate multiple inheritance using interfaces. If multiple inheritance with classes were allowed, it would lead to the [Diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).
For reasons multiple inheritance is not supported, I suggest you read [Why doesn't C# support multiple inheritance?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/why-doesnt-c-support-multiple-inheritance)

> Different languages actually have
> different expectations for how MI
> works. For example, how conflicts are
> resolved and whether duplicate bases
> are merged or redundant. Before we can
> implement MI in the CLR, we have to do
> a survey of all the languages, figure
> out the common concepts, and decide
> how to express them in a
> language-neutral manner. We would also
> have to decide whether MI belongs in
> the CLS and what this would mean for
> languages that don't want this concept
> (presumably VB.NET, for example). Of
> course, that's the business we are in
> as a common language runtime, but we
> haven't got around to doing it for MI
> yet.
>
> The number of places where MI is truly
> appropriate is actually quite small.
> In many cases, multiple interface
> inheritance can get the job done
> instead. In other cases, you may be
> able to use encapsulation and
> delegation. If we were to add a
> slightly different construct, like
> mixins, would that actually be more
> powerful?
>
> Multiple implementation inheritance
> injects a lot of complexity into the
> implementation. This complexity
> impacts casting, layout, dispatch,
> field access, serialization, identity
> comparisons, verifiability,
> reflection, generics, and probably
> lots of other places.

Answer (score 1):

In general, multiple inheritance creates more problems than it solves. Think about how virtual method calls have to be resolved. What if a class doesn't define a method but both of its parents do? Which one should execute?

Implementing multiple interfaces, however, has no such problems. If two interfaces define the same method and you actually try to implement them, your code won't even compile (although I'm unsure if you could explicitly implement them and satisfy the compiler requirements).

Comment: You can explicitly define them both

Comment: There shouldn't be any compiler error while implementing a method which both interfaces define.

Answer (score 1):

> Because interfaces do not the
>   implementation details, they only know
>   what operations an object can do.
>   **Multiple inheritance is difficult when
>   there are two different
>   implementations are found for the
>   method with same signature in both the
>   base classes.** But in case of interface
>   both the interface may define a common
>   method with same signature but they
>   are not implemented at the interface
>   level, they are only implemented by
>   the object or type that implement both
>   the interfaces. Here **though there are
>   two different interfaces defining two
>   methods with same signatures, the
>   object provides the common
>   implementation satisfying both the
>   methods in both the interfaces.** So
>   **there is no ambiguity between
>   implementations**, both the methods have
>   common implementation hence you could
>   have multiple inheritance in case of
>   interfaces.

Comment: What are you quoting?

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inheritance means getting the properties from one class object to another class object.

Here in the interface concept we are not at all getting any properties, rather we are implementing the unimplemented methods of interface in class.

So inheritance and intefaces are quite opposite...

So finally java supports only syntax of multiple inheritance does not supports implementation of multiple inheritance....

Inheritance is like debit and interface is like credit....but interface has its own importance in other concepts like server side programming...

Comment: This plagiarises [saidesh kilaru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437563/multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-net-but-are-multiple-interfaces-suppo/13878203#13878203).

Answer (score 0):

The danger with multiple inheritance of concrete classes is that there is storage and virtual method lookup that must be reconciled between the two or more parents of a given class.  Especially tricky is when there are shared ancestors.  But interfaces only define what a class should look like, not how it needs to be implemented and it's much easier to make a class look like a lot of different things than it is to make it *be* a lot of different things.  Two interfaces can require a method int Foo() and an implementing class can safely use both interfaces and implement Foo() without causing headaches for which base Foo() to override, etc.

Another reason is that constructor chaining is difficult to manage with multiple inheritance.  But interfaces don't specify constructors, so that problem is entirely sidestepped.

There are certainly many other reasons why multiple inheritance is bad.

Answer (score -1):

Java supports syntactical multiple inheritance. Java does not supports implementation of multiple inheritance.

Some people says Java supports multiple inheritance through interfaces ...but its not correct here the explanation:

inheritance ::

getting the properties from one class object to another class object..

Class A{}

Class B extends A {}

Here object of class A getting the properties(methods/functions/ & data members/class variables)

Why Java does not supports multiple inheritance using classes:

Class A{} Class B{} Class C extends A,B{} X--this statement causes error because Class A getting object of object class from both sides A and B.

Every Java class by default extending Object of object class. And Object of object class is the root object means super class for all classes.

but here Class c having two super classes of object. So giving error. It means Java does not support multiple inheritance by using classes.

is Java supports multiple inheritance using Interfaces:

Because of this interface concept, only few of us are saying that Java supports multiple inheritance. But it's wrong.

Here is the explanation::

interface A{}

interface B{}

interface C implements A , B{}

(or) interface A{}

interface B{}

Class C implements A , B{}

Here it looks like multiple inheritance, but:

Inheritance means getting the properties from one class object to another class object.

Here in interface concept we are not at all getting any properties rather we are implementing the unimplemented methods of interface in class.

So inheritance and intefaces are quite opposite.

So finally Java supports only syntax of multiple inheritance does not supports implementation of multiple inheritance.

Inheritance is like debit and interface is like credit. But an interface has its own importance in other concepts like server-side programming.

Comment: This is self-plagiarism of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13878078/1) posted 10 minutes earlier.