# VB.net Inherits 2 Classes

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, multiple-inheritance

Is it possible to inherit from two classes in VB.net?

We are developing Custom User Controls that inherits from say System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label. We are planning on implementing a bunch of these controls but they will share mostly the same **additional properties**. We are hopeful about centralising these properties.

I have looked into interfaces but it seems they only 'contract' properties you need to implement.

Thoughts?

Comment: Consider just using [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/178368/284240

Answer (score 2):

No.  It is not possible for VB.net types to inherit more than one class.  It is possible to implement an infinite number of interfaces but inheritance is limited to one type.

Note: This is not an arbitrary VB.Net restriction.  It's actually a restriction that is baked into the CLR.  Languages like C++/CLI get around this with some very interesting type flattening routines but at a CLR level they use single inheritance.

Comment: Thanks JaredPar - any suggestion to the best way we implement this situation? Forget centralising and just implement properties in each?

Comment: @timmah.faase I would put the common functionality into a single class  and then have the users simply have a field of that type and use same named properties to forward into the field type.  And likely create interfaces for the shared functionality

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot inherit from two classes.

However, we faced exactly the same issue that you do and solved it in the following manner:

1) We created an interface that was implemented by each of the controls so that they could be easily discoverable.

2) We created a settings class that contained settings and logic that were common to all classes.

3) We added a property to the interface created in 1 to expose the settings class so that we could perform standard actions on all properties.