# inherit from two classes in C#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Multiple Inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp)

I have two classes Class A and Class B. These two classes cannot inherit each other. I am creating new class called Class C. Now, I want to implement the methods in class A and class B by inheriting. I am aware that multiple inheritance is not possible in C# but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You should probably be using an interface...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Multitiple inheritance is not possible in C#, however it can be simulated using interfaces, see [Simulated Multiple Inheritance Pattern for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10072/Simulated-Multiple-Inheritance-Pattern-for-C).

The basic idea is to define an interface for the members on class `B` that you wish to access (call it `IB`), and then have `C` inherit from `A` and implement `IB` by internally storing an instance of `B`, for example:

```
class C : A, IB
{
    private B _b = new B();

    // IB members
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _b.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

There are also a couple of other alternaitve patterns explained on that page.

Answer (score 20):

A common alternative to inheritance is delegation (also called composition): X "has a" Y rather than X "is a" Y.
So if class `A` has functionality for dealing with Foos, class `B` has functionality for dealing with Bars, and you want both in class `C`, then you can do something like this:

```
public class A() {
  private FooManager fooManager = new FooManager(); // (or inject, if you have IoC)

  public void handleFoo(Foo foo) {
    fooManager.handleFoo(foo);
  }
}

public class B() {
  private BarManager barManager = new BarManager(); // (or inject, if you have IoC)

  public void handleBar(Bar bar) {
    barManager.handleBar(bar);
  }
}

public class C() {
  private FooManager fooManager = new FooManager(); // (or inject, if you have IoC)
  private BarManager barManager = new BarManager(); // (or inject, if you have IoC)

  // ... etc.
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to literally use the method code from `A` and `B` you can make your `C` class contain an instance of each. If you code against interfaces for `A` and `B` then your clients don't need to know you're giving them a `C` rather than an `A` or a `B`.

```
interface IA { void SomeMethodOnA(); }
interface IB { void SomeMethodOnB(); }
class A : IA { void SomeMethodOnA() { /* do something */ } }
class B : IB { void SomeMethodOnB() { /* do something */ } }
class C : IA, IB
{
    private IA a = new A();
    private IB b = new B();
    void SomeMethodOnA() { a.SomeMethodOnA(); }
    void SomeMethodOnB() { b.SomeMethodOnB(); }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):

```
class ClassC
{
    public ClassA A { get; set; }
    public ClassB B { get; set; }   

    public C (ClassA  a, ClassB  b)
    {
        this.A = a;
        this.B = b;
    }
}
```

Then you can call `C.A.DoA()`. You also can change the properties to an interface or abstract class, like `public InterfaceA A` or `public AbstractClassA A`.

Answer (score 6):

Make two interfaces `IA` and `IB`:

```
public interface IA
{
    public void methodA(int value);
}

public interface IB
{
    public void methodB(int value);
}
```

Next make `A` implement `IA` and `B` implement `IB`.

```
public class A : IA
{
    public int fooA { get; set; }
    public void methodA(int value) { fooA = value; }
}

public class B : IB
{
    public int fooB { get; set; }
    public void methodB(int value) { fooB = value; }
}
```

Then implement your C class as follows:

```
public class C : IA, IB
{
    private A _a;
    private B _b;

    public C(A _a, B _b)
    {
        this._a = _a;
        this._b = _b;
    }

    public void methodA(int value) { _a.methodA(value); }
    public void methodB(int value) { _b.methodB(value); }
}
```

Generally this is a poor design overall because you can have both `A` and `B` implement a method with the same name and variable types such as `foo(int bar)` and you will need to decide how to implement it, or if you just call `foo(bar)` on both `_a` and `_b`. As suggested elsewhere you should consider a `.A` and `.B` properties instead of combining the two classes.

Comment: `public ` is not a valid keyword for interface member definitions ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a base class for `A` and `B` where you can hold a *common* methods/properties/fields of those.

After implement `C:Base`.

Or in order to simulate multiple inheritance, define a common `interface`(s) and implement them in `C`

Hope this helps.

Comment: If i use interface then I need to define the methods in Class C. Is there any other way where I can directly call the methods?

Comment: @Virus: you don't need to define **all** methods, but only those you want to *share* between different types.

Answer (score -5):

Do you mean you want Class C to be the base class for A & B in that case.

```
public abstract class C
{
    public abstract void Method1();

    public abstract void Method2();
}

public class A : C
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class B : C
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question