# Method that accepts only classes that implement a specific interface

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have the following method

```
    private void PushToMainWindow(UserControl child) // where child is IMainWindowPlugin
    {
        _navigationStack.Push((IMainWindowPlugin)child);
        ...
        // Here I do stuff that makes use of the child as a usercontrol
        child.Width = 500;
        child.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
        ...
    }
```

What I would like to do is inform the compiler that I'll only be accepting UserControl objects that also implement the IMainWindowPlugin interface.

I know I can do a if statement and throw or cast and check for null, but those are both run-time solutions, and I'm looking for a way to tell the developer up front that there is a restriction on the type of UserControl he can add. Is there a way to say this in c# ?

UPDATE:
Added more code to show that the usercontrol is used as a usercontrol, so I can't just pass the child as the interface.

Comment: If IMainWindowPlugin is your interface you can create base class that inherits from UserControl and have empty implementation for this interface. Also check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you consider generics? Something like this should work:

```
    private void PushToMainWindow<T>(T child) where T: UserControl, IMainWindowPlugin
    {
        var windowPlugin = child as IMainWindowPlugin;
        _navigationStack.Push(windowPlugin);
        ...
        // Here I do stuff that makes use of the child as a usercontrol
        child.Width = 500;
        child.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
        ...
    }
```

Compiler will not allow for passing to the `PushToMainWindow()` method objects that are not meeting the `where` clause, which means that the class you are passing has to be `UserControl` (or derived) and implement `IMainWindowPlugin`.

Other thing is, that probably passing the interface itself is better idea, instead of basing on concrete implementation.

Comment: this really looks like a good solution, with the system automatically completing T

Comment: Generics are very useful. Refer to MSDN to dig into the topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented this solution, and its working 100%

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
void PushToMainWindow(IMainWindowPlugin child) { ... }
```

Comment: ok, that would make sense, let me add more detail to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void PushToMainWindow(IMainWindowPlugin child) 
    {
        _navigationStack.Push(child);
        var newChild=(UserControl )child
        newChild.Width = 500;
        newChild.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
    }
```

Comment: It just inverts the problem, I would prefer that both conditions are met, thanks tho!