# Base class as type

Tags: c#

Since I can't have multiple base classes, I am looking forward to pass a base class as a type. Is it possible in c#?

Example:

```
public class MyClass : Base1<Base2> {}

public class Base1<TBase> : TBase 
{
    m1();
}

public class Base2
{
    m2();
}
```

This way I can access m1() and m2() from MyClass

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope generics don't work that way.

Comment: this sounds like the xy problem. what are you hoping to accomplish? can you use interfaces?

Comment: Use composition instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested in the comments, you should probably use [composition instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178368/781792) of trying to have multiple inheritance. In your case, that might look something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Base1 Base1 { get; set; }
    public Base2 Base2 { get; set; }
}

public class Base1
{
    public void m1() { }
}

public class Base2
{
    public void m2() { }
}


// use like
myClass.Base1.m1();
```