# C# - Having an object from multiple classes

Tags: c#

I have three different classes in my current project structured as below:

```
class BaseClass {
    public string prop1;
    public string prop2;
    public string prop3;
}
class C1 : BaseClass {
    public string prop3;   // Common with class C2
    public string prop4;
}
class C2 : BaseClass {
    public string prop3;   // Common with class C1
    public string prop5;
}
```

I need to have an object which includes prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, and prop5; but I don't want to have a duplication definition. I **don't** want to create a new class like this:

```
class NewClass {
    public string prop1;
    public string prop2;
    public string prop3;
    public string prop4;
    public string prop5;
}
```

Is there a way (like interface, or abstract class, or anything else) that I can refactor my old classes into so that I can have an object with all 5 properties without defining a new class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Inheritance in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely interfaces, just be aware that for matter of theory correctness, you would be implementing methods, not properties, a property is something different in C#. (Link: [Properties in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx))

```
public interface IBaseClass
{
    public string GetProperty1();
    public string GetProperty2();
    public string GetProperty3();
}

public interface IC1
{
    public string GetProperty4();
}

public interface IC2
{
    public string GetProperty5();
}


public class Implementation : IBaseClass, IC1, IC2
{
    public string GetProperty1()
    {
        return "Value";
    }
    public string GetProperty2()
    {
        return "Value";
    }
    public string GetProperty3()
    {
        return "Value";
    }
    public string GetProperty4()
    {
        return "Value";
    }
    public string GetProperty5()
    {
        return "Value";
    }


}
```

The benefit of doing it like this, is that the implementation class is forced to define such methods.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
    class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual string prop1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string prop2 { get; set; }
        public virtual string prop3 { get; set; }
        public virtual string prop4 { get; set; }
        public virtual string prop5 { get; set; }
    }
    class C1 : BaseClass
    {
        public override string prop4 { get; set; }
    }

    class C2 : BaseClass
    {
        public override string prop5 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but no! In this case C2 has prop4 as a member and I don't want it. I don't want C2 to have any access to prop4.

Comment: Your question says "I need to have an object which includes prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, and prop5;". can you explain what you meant by that? From your question, I thought objects of any of the classes should have all the properties.