# How to inherit without using interfaces

Tags: c#

Theese are my classes:

```
class Reply {
}

class VotableReply : Reply {
}

class Question : VotableReply {
}

class Answer : VotableReply {
}

class Comment : Reply {
}
```

Now, I want to add new class which will be common to `Comment` and `Answer`. But I cant really do that, because `Answer` and `Question` has common ancesor.

[I think graph is easier to visualize problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKOfA.png)

So, is there any way to add new class without using interfaces?

Comment: [Multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp) isn't supported by .NET, so an interface is _probably_ your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, inheritance is not the best choice. Maybe, it's better to use composition here:

```
class NewClass : Reply {
    private Comment comment;
    private Answer answer;

    NewClass() {
        comment = new Comment();
        answer = new Answer();
    }

    void CommentMethod() {
        comment.CommentMethod();
    }

    void AnswerMethod() {
        answer.AnswerMethod();
    }
}
```

So, now `NewClass` has functionality of `Comment` and `Answer`.
Also, you can replace `Reply` with an interface, or add a new interface.