# Do we really have to wrap components when using compositing

Tags: c#, interface, traits, composition

When multiple classes implement one (or more) interface, despite being different classes, they might have a lot of logic in common and only differ slightly.

In that case, it may be handy to move the shared logic into a shared class, which is then used as a component. Calls of methods with a shared logic are delegated to that component.

For exemple :

```
interface IFoo
{
    void DoFoo();
}

interface IBar
{
    void DoBar();
}

interface IBaz
{
    void DoBaz();
}

class DefaultFoo()
{
    public void Do() { /* Shared logic */ }
}

class DefaultBar()
{
    public void Do() { /* Shared logic */ }
}

class FooBarBaz1 : IFoo, IBar, IBaz
{
    DefaultFoo defaultFoo = new DefaultFoo();
    DefaultBar defaultBar = new DefaultBar();

    public void DoFoo() { defaultFoo.Do(); }
    public void DoBar() { defaultBar.Do(); }
    public void DoBaz() { /* FooBarBaz1 specific IBaz implementation */ }
}

class FooBarBaz2 : IFoo, IBar, IBaz
{
    DefaultFoo defaultFoo = new DefaultFoo();

    public void Foo() { defaultFoo.Do(); }
    public void Bar() { /* FooBarBaz2 specific IBar implementation */ }
    public void Baz() { /* FooBarBaz2 specific IBaz implementation */ }
}

// More ForBarBazX classes...
```

In classes `FooBarBaz1` and `FooBarBaz2`, we completely wrap the `DefaultFoo` instance to give the impression from the public side that `FooBarBaz1` and `FooBarBaz2` are doing the work while they are just delegating it.

The problem with that is, if you have a large number of classes that must implement the interface and / or the interface has many methods, you end up being force to write a lot of "useless" delegation code.

**So my question is : can't we just NOT wrap the shared logic ?** Instead of requiring the methods to be implemented, the interfaces require to have these components exposed.

We would have instead :

```
interface IFoo
{
    DefaultFoo Foo { get; }
}

interface IBar
{
    DefaultBar Bar { get; }
}

interface IBaz
{
    DefaultBaz Baz { get; }
}

class DefaultFoo()
{
    public virtual void Do() { /* Shared logic */ } // Note the virtual.
}

class DefaultBar()
{
    public virtual void Do() { /* Shared logic */ } // Note the virtual.
}

class FooBarBaz1 : IFoo, IBar, IBaz
{
    private class SpecificBaz : DefaultBaz
    {
        public override void DoBaz() { /* Specific logic */ }
    }

    public DefaultFoo Foo { get; private set; }
    public DefaultBar Bar { get; private set; }
    public DefaultBaz Baz { get; private set; }

    public FooBarBaz1()
    {
        Foo = new DefaultFoo();
        Bar = new DefaultBar();
        Baz = new SpecificBaz();
    }
}

class FooBarBaz2 : IFoo, IBar, IBaz
{
    private class SpecificBar : DefaultBar
    {
        public override void Bar() { /* Specific logic */ }
    }

    private class SpecificBaz : DefaultBaz
    {
        public override void Baz() { /* Specific logic */ }
    }

    public DefaultFoo Foo { get; private set; }
    public DefaultBar Bar { get; private set; }
    public DefaultBaz Baz { get; private set; }

    public FooBarBaz1()
    {
        Foo = new DefaultFoo();
        Bar = new SpecificBaz();
        Baz = new SpecificBaz();
    }
}
```

Than, instead of doing :

```
ForBarBaz1 fooBarBaz = new ForBarBaz1();
fooBarBaz.Foo();
fooBarBaz.Bar();
fooBarBaz.Baz();
```

One would access the exposed components :

```
ForBarBaz1 fooBarBaz = new ForBarBaz1();
fooBarBaz.Foo.Do();
fooBarBaz.Bar.Do();
fooBarBaz.Baz.Do();
```

What do you think about this ? It seems to be like it preserves modularity while avoiding the large amounts of "useless" wrapping code.

PS : I'm asking this for C# but I guess it would also apply to some other languages.

Comment: There's easier ways to do compositon.  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178368/585968) with the novel use of extension methods.  Makes it much simpler

Comment: Vote to move this into [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @virus721 comment is implied.  Simply click the close link and it will show you the breakdown of votes and a description as to _"why"_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp).  Though the titles may be different, the net aim is the same.   Of particular note is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178368/585968)

Comment: @MickyD Thanks for your comment. It really ressembles what I did in the second part, execpt that the answer also includes some extensions methods that might have been included in the exposed components `SteeringWheel` and `BreakPedal`. What is so much different ? Thanks.

Comment: @yorodm this code would be too generic for CR, and thus would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The _difference_ is that callers do not refer to the composition objects directly.  Instead of `fooBarBaz.Foo.Do()` you would just perform a `fooBarBaz.Do()`

Comment: Ho I see. Instead of accessing components, you instead do some wrapping / delegation, but using some extension methods on the interface instead, so that it's not necessary to do it in every implementing class. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @MickyD Also, what about properties ? Extension methods allow factoring the wrapping / delegating code for methods, but it doesn't help with properties !

Comment: Yes it's quite an efficient trick. I read somewhere that c# extension "methods" may soon address properties too. I can't tell you how much joy that will bring programmers :)