# How to use one base class and one abstract together in a class

Tags: .net, oop, c#-4.0

I have one class which is already inherits with base class and i need to use some function from another abstract class. how to do that because a class can not inherit more than one class.

```
public Class ABC : BaseClass, SomeAbstractClass
{
}
```

need to have above functionality. can someone please help me out to do this in c#.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Unlike C++, C# does not support multiple base classes.

What you can do is inherit the abstract class, and implement an interface that have been extracted from the base class - and instead of inherit from the base class, have a field of it's type (in short, use composition over inheritance):

```
public Class ABC : SomeAbstractClass, IBaseClass
{
    private IBaseClass _base;

    // initialize the IBaseClass in your constructor:

    public ABC(int a, string b)
        : base(a) // assume a constructor that takes an int on the abstract class
    {
        _base = new BaseClass(b); // assume a constructor that takes a string on the base class
    }

    // or a constructor for Dependency Injection:
    public ABC(int a, IBaseClass baseClass)
        : base(a)
    {
         _base = baseClass;
    }

    // implement the interface like this:

    public int SomeIBaseClassMethod(string a, int b)
    {
        return _base.SomeBaseClassMethod(a, b);
    }

    public bool IsValid 
    {
        get {return _base.IsValid;} 
        set {_base.IsValid = value}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance is not supported in C#. What you can do is implement different interfaces.

```
public class ABC: BaseClass, ISomeOtherInterface {

}
```

Comment: so how to use SomeAbstractClass inside an interface?

Comment: This [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp) describes the usage of multiple interfaces...

Comment: @PeterSchneider - the point is, they can't just instantiate the abstract class and wrap it or anything else like that. A better suggestion would be to inherit from the abstract class (which has to be inherited from anyway to be useful) and wrap a `BaseClass` instance.