# How to convert IdentityUser to BaseEntity

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I have user Model, like this:

```
    public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
       //... more lines
    }
```

Now I need to use some methods for user, that are made for base entity, so I want to add Base Entity, but it does not work.

```
    public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>, BaseEntity
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
       //... more lines
    }
```

I tried creating new user with only BaseEntity and then it works, but then I lose all the methods for IdentityUser which I don't want.

Comment: `IdentityUser` and `BaseEntity` are both classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp)

Comment: IdentityUser and BaseEntity are classes. I will look into multiple inheritance, thanks but I read somewhere that this can be done using mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since multiple inheritance is not possible in C#, you could have an `IdentityUser` as a field and wrap the properties and methods you want (assuming `IdentityUser` is not your own class):

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IdentityUser<Guid> _identityUser;
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _identityUser.UserName; }
        set { _identityUser.UserName = value; }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _identityUser.Id; }
        set { _identityUser.Id = value ; } 
    }

    // ... etc.

    public User(IdentityUser<Guid> identityUser)
    {
        _identityUser = identityUser;
    }
}
```