# Inherit a Class from 2 base classes one is my class other is AspNet IdentityUser

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a `Person` entity class which is inherit from my `BaseEntity`. The project structure is on that base entity class so i cannot change or remove it.

I want to implement another base class `IdentityUser` coming from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`

But this is getting error: **Class 'Person' cannot have multiple base classes: 'BaseEntity' and 'IdentityUser'**

Is there any way to solve this ?

```
public class Person : BaseEntity, IdentityUser
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public int PrivilegeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    ........
    ........
    ........
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# is not like C++. It is not possible to inherit form more than on base class. Maybe you should convert IdentityUser to an interface.

```cs
public interface IIdentityUser
{
  int GroupId { get; set; }
  int PrivilegeId { get; set; }
  // ...
}

public class Person : BaseEntity, IIdentityUser
{
  public int GroupId { get; set; }
  public string CardNumber { get; set; }
  public int PrivilegeId { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```

In multiple inheritance systems the diamond problem can occurr (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)). Also there is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Thank you i'll look at that discussion also