# How to mulitiply inherit from abstract base classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have some abstract base classes to be used on multiple implementations.

Base classes:

```
public abstract class BaseX
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseY : BaseX
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

For each use case, I want to create from these base classes specific classes like:

```
public abstract SpecificX : BaseX
{
    public string C { get; set; }
}

public abstract SpecificY : BaseY
{
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

All classes that derive from `SpecificY` should contain all the properties A, B, C, D.

My problem now is, that `SpecificY` doesn't have the property C from `SpecificX`, because I cannot do multiple inheritance like

```
public abstract SpecificY : BaseY, SpecificX
```

My only idea would be to use Interface like this:

```
public Interface ISpecificX
{
    string C { get; set; }
}

public abstract SpecificX : BaseX, ISpecificX
{
    public string C { get; set; }
}

public abstract SpecificY : BaseY, ISpecificY
{
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; } <== redundancy
}
```

But then I'd need to implement C twice. And as soon as C is becoming more than a simple Property, things get ugly. Is there a better way to create this structure?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: insteaf of **inheriting** you may consider to **use** instances of what you think your base-class should be. This way you can have one, or two or even none at all of those properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Inheritance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp) and look for [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178368/585968) on _composition_.

Comment: please correct your question as I can't see any class like `SpecificB` or `SpecificA` from it

Comment: Sorry, misstyping with SpecificB|A ... corrected it in the question

Comment: @MickyD Thanks for the link. It's not really answering the question, or let's say, I am very unhappy with a composition solution and would probably rather do a Interface workaround to reduce the overhead to redundancy in SpecificY and what lies beyond

Comment: @Aaginor _"[composition]...Thanks for the link. It's not really answering the question"_ - considering you stated _"My problem now is... `I cannot do multiple inheritance`"_ and a C# _["class can have only **one direct base class**"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance)_ the popularity of the link would seem to suggest otherwise.   You also mentioned _"redundancy"_, that's something composition/aggregation can help to alleviate.

Comment: What's not working: Attributes, Inheritance (So a function that takes a SpecificX cannot take a SpecificY), Redundancy (why do you have this in "exclamation marks"?)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to [favour composition over inhertiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#:%7E:text=To%20favor%20composition%20over%20inheritance,gives%20the%20design%20higher%20flexibility.&text=Initial%20design%20is%20simplified%20by,business-domain%20classes%20via%20inheritance.) - as propsed by the GoF. This way you do not **inherit** a given class, but just **use** an instance of it. Then you can easily have all your properties without any duplication:

```
class BaseX { ... }
class BaseY { ... }

class SpecificY : BaseY
{
    private readonly SpecificX b = new SpecificX();
    public string A { get => this.b.A; set => this.b.A = value; } // delegate the call
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get => this.b.C; set => this.b.C = value; } // delegate the call
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem with composition-over-inheritance is that you can't pass a composed (member) object around as though it were a reference to its owner - nor can you override methods either. Composition-over-inheritance works best in languages based on message-passing (like Smalltalk and Objective-C) or languages with first-class support for mixins and traits (thus allowing for polymorphism). C# has neither message-passing or traits - which makes polymorphic class-composition a very painful and frustrating experience.

Comment: Yes, f.e. if I want to pass a variable of type SpecificX, I can't pass an object of SpecificY. Also, I very often use the construct: if (myObject is SpecificX specificXInstance) { ... } which would not work with composition. 
This could be solved with Interfaces, but then I am back at start, because I need to make sure that all new properties/methods from SpecificX are in SpecificY as well.

Comment: Also, I use attributes for the properties, which would probably not appear on the delegated properties.

Comment: @Aaginor _"if I want to pass a variable of type SpecificX, I can't pass an object of SpecificY"_ - that is a limitation of your code and is present whether composition is used or not.  The only commonality in your two graphs is that that `SpecificX` and `SpecificY` ultimately derive from `BaseX` so there is nothing stopping you from passing an instance of `SpecificY` in this case.  Also performing explicit checks like `if (myObject is SpecificX specificXInstance) ` defeats the purpose of OOP.  I think you need to rethink your trees

Comment: @MickyD Well, this is exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: @Aaginor what I am saying is that your inheritence trees don't appear to make sense. 
e.g.  if you were to replace `BaseX`, `BaseY`, `SpecificX` and `SpecificY` with say  `Animal`, `Dog`, `Cat` and `Husky` you will soon see why `public abstract SpecificY : BaseY, SpecificX` doesn't work. There is no creature on Earth that had a cat as one parent and a dog for another...a husky one at that! ;)  Your example of _"I want to pass a variable of type SpecificX, I can't pass an object of SpecificY"_ _can_ hold true if the method was fine to work on `Animal`.  Hope this helps