# Unity Inheritance & scope

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

C++ Developer trying to get started in Unity here.

I've been playing around in Unity and watching some videos / reading the documentation.
I have a couple of questions on inheritance and I hoping someone can point me to something helpful.

MonoBehaviour: this seems to be the standard, most scripts will use this, it is attached to a gameobject and is 'generally' destroyed with the scene.

ScriptableObject: allows you to create 'assets' outside of the scene, which have persistence.

: testing has shown that you can create 'normal' classes and Instantiate them inside of inherited classes with 'new'.

Is it possible to inherit from more than one class? I assume so, but what are the rules here?

Can I do:

Baseclass

SubClass : ScriptableObject, Baseclass

OR

Baseclass

SubClass : MonoBehaviour, Baseclass

etc?
Or do I have to use the same inheritance everytime? ie.

Baseclass : ScriptableObject

SubClass : ScriptableObject, Baseclass

Also can how do I get a 'ScriptableObject' into a scene?
I have managed to do as so:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/PlayerData", order = 2)]

public class PlayerData: ScriptableObject
{
    public int maxHealth;
    public PlayerDictionary.PlayerEnum playerEnum;
}

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerDictionary : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerData[] playersInGroup;
    private readonly Dictionary<PlayerEnum, PlayerData> playerFinder = new Dictionary<PlayerEnum, PlayerData>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= playersInGroup.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            playerFinder.Add(playersInGroup[x].playerEnum, playersInGroup[x]);
        }
    }

    public PlayerData FindPlayer(PlayerEnum type)
    {
        PlayerData ret = null;
        playerFinder.TryGetValue(type, out ret);
        return ret;
    }

    public enum PlayerEnum
    {
        TILE_TYPE_NONE = 0,
        TILE_TYPE_ENEMY,
        TILE_TYPE_ENEMY_ALT1,
        TILE_TYPE_ENEMY_ALT2
    }
}
```

One final thing:
How do keep things in scope?

I have two ways;

1. static vars in a class, the is not in the scene at all.
2. DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

Are there other / better methods to keep things in scope when switching scenes?

Comment: _"Is it possible to inherit from more than one class? I assume so, but what are the rules here?"_ - no, C# does not allow that.  It's nothing to do with Unity.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a reason I preferred C++ :)

Comment: Haha I'm with you there! :)

Comment: Also check out [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178368/585968) as a way to almost get around it.

Comment: Finally, [Native plug-ins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html)

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to inherit from more than one class?

No, you can't inherit from multiple classes, but you can implement multiple [interfaces](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/interfaces#)

> I have two ways;
>
> 1. static vars in a class, the is not in the scene at all.
> 2. `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)`;

This is the preferred way of keeping game objects across all scenes, this can be achieved by the following code

```cs
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static SomeClass instance;
    // other variables

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    // other methods
}
```

A bit of explanation here, the first time the scene loads, `instance` is `null`. In the `Awake()` method, we set `instance` to `this`, which refers to this script and we set `DontDestroyOnLoad()`. So when you switch scenes, the gameobject to which this script is attached stays in the hierarchy. But when you reload the same scene, you don't want a duplicate of this gameobject. If you are reloading into this same scene, all the gameobjects get created in which there will also be a gameobject that was set to `DontDestroyOnLoad()` previously. Now in the newly created gameobject, the script's `instance` is not null this time, hence it gets destroyed. Finally, there's only one gameobject with this script, that was previously set to `DontDestroyOnLoad()`.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't come across interfaces yet, I'll look into it! But singletons are the 'preferred' method, alot of people would debate that haha. Its how I've been doing it so far, but I was hoping to find an alternative. ;) Thanks again.

Comment: What about getting scriptables into the scene? Do you know a good video / documention on that? So far I can only do this by adding it to a MonoB as either a reference, or as above using a list.

Comment: _"but you can **inherit** from multiple interfaces"_ - the correct term is _implements_ not inherit.  _["An interface defines a contract. **A class or struct that implements an interface** shall adhere to its contract..."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces)_.  Otherwise good +1